# Toggle button Pause / Unpause Audio Listener

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

How my toggle button, can pause and unpause the Audio Listener from my main camera? OR Stop and Play again that Listener

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
In the inspector, I dragged the camera, inside the On Value Changed (boolean) of the Toggle Button, selected Audio Listener> Enable.

Is toggle ON all sounds play, if OFF, all songs pause.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When disabling the AudioListener the editor outputs a warning on each frame.

The best solution is to write a small script with a `Listen(bool)` function bound to the OnClick().

```
 public void Listen(bool listening) {                   
         AudioListener.pause = !listening;    
 }
```

**Note:**
You cannot change the AudioListener via GetComponent because it is a static singleton. There should always only be one AudioListener.